# How to open an app if it is already downloaded otherwise open itunes download page

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In my app, I want to open an application download page on App Store. But if it is already downloaded I want to direct users to application. When I give `URL` such as https://itunes.apple.com/......, app store is opening. But the problem is it always opens app store page although the app is already downloaded. Is it possible to open application if it is downloaded. Thank you for your responses.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APPSTORE_URL]];
```

Comment: Do you want to open your app having it already launched? Sound strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlSchemeOfYourApp])
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlSchemeOfYourApp];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APPSTORE_URL]];
}
```

Here, first you are checking whether your app is installed on the device or not, if installed opening the app, if not installed opening the iTunes store.